# Openshift containers running in privileged mode

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Being absolutely new to openshift, i'm curious how i can check if any of the running containers are running in "privileged" mode (openshift v4.6). Digging in the documentation and searching the net i could only find information regarding SCCs, which is great and all, but i didnt find anything regarding this (apart from an older version of openshift, where the `oc get pods` (or something similar command) used to show if a pod was running with such privileges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default pods use the Restricted SCC. The pod's SCC is determined by the User/ServiceAccount and/or Group. Then, you also have to consider that a SA may or may not be bound to a Role, which can set a list of available SCCs.

To find out what SCC a pod runs under:

```sh
oc get pod $POD_NAME -o yaml | grep openshift.io/scc
```

The following commands can also be useful:

```sh
# get pod's SA name
oc get pod $POD_NAME -o yaml | grep serviceAccount:
# list service accounts that can use a particular SCC
oc adm policy who-can use scc privileged
# list users added by the oc adm policy command
oc get scc privileged -o yaml
# check roles and role bindings of your SA
# you need to look at rules.apiGroups: security.openshift.io
oc get rolebindings -o wide
oc get role $ROLE_NAME -o yaml
```

Comment: Wonderful! thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

An OpenShift project comes with 3 service accounts by default which are builder, default, deployer.

The containers you deploy to that namespace will be assigned to "default" service account and that is the one which has "restricted" scc role.

You can find more here: https://www.openshift.com/blog/managing-sccs-in-openshift